# Bootstrap slider shifted to the right

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 to make my site. When I did slider and when I opened this page on mobile the image was shifted to the right, outside the viewport.

In firefox, slider doesn't work, any solution?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.0/flatly/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="{{ url('assets/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Social</title>
</head>
```

http://scr.hu/0lw/816la

HTML:

```
    <div id="carousel-example-generic2" class="carousel slide">

  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol> 
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="assets/images/s1.jpg" alt="" >
      <!-- Opis slajdu -->
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
        <p>Suspendisse fermentum arcu et ligula rhoncus dapibus.</p>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="item">
      <img src="assets/images/s2.jpg" alt="">
      <!-- Opis slajdu -->
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
        <p>Suspendisse fermentum arcu et ligula rhoncus dapibus.</p>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="item">
      <img src="assets/images/s3.jpg" alt="">
      <!-- Opis slajdu -->
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
        <p>Suspendisse fermentum arcu et ligula rhoncus dapibus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic2" data-slide="prev">

   <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>

<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic2" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

In css I changed nothing.

Comment: What is your HTML and CSS?

Comment: It is more easy to help you with your issue if you post your code or you could isolate the issue and make a bootply.

Comment: It's probably inside another div that has a width on it. You're supposed to put the carousel, if it's full width, outside all grid classes and outside the .container or .container fluid

Comment: Nope, It isn't inside another div, maybe mobile firefox doesn't support this.

Comment: Please make a fiddle, because some other element is making you the problem, not carousel

Comment: Ok, I just set margin-top on slider and this didn't work because of this

Answer (score 0):

You have a set min-width that is wider than the viewport of whatever device you're viewing this one. That is why it won't be seen. Add this to your head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```